# Laravel static asset injecting using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I do have a markup I want to inject using javascript after loading the page. But the problem is that markup contains some static assets which are invoked using the Laravel url method. As this url method works in server-side renders, specifically in blade, src only gets the string instead of src url.

In Blade

```
 <div id="card_container"></div>
```

In common_script.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const data = `<div class="bg-box-gradient">
            <img src="{{ url('frontend/landing-page/images/Mask-Group-69.png') }}" alt=""> //is it possible to run that server-side url method in client-side rendering?
            </div>`;

    document.getElementById("card_container").innerHTML = data;
});
```

Is it possible to run that server-side url method in client-side rendering?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write **url or any laravel function** you have to write in **.blade** file it self in external .js file you cannot write so you can write in  tag it self it will work

**{{ }}** will work only in blade file